# change dropdown to textBox in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I am stuck in a place in Yii. I have two drop Down box, second is dependent on the first. In this first drop Down, I have many options. By referring to these options, I must decide whether the second box must be a drop Down or a text Field.
I have uploaded My code here. Please help me solving this.
Thanks in advance.

My View:

```
<td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cm_classification_id'); ?>        
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_classification_id', CHtml::listData(masterClassification::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'cm_classification_id ASC', 'condition'=>'cm_classification_type=:type', 'params'=>array('type'=>'initiate'))), 'cm_classification_id', 'cm_classification_name'),  array('empty'=>'Select classification')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'cm_classification_id'); ?>

    </td>

<td>
    <label>Change Description <span class="required" id="desc_req_note" style="display:none;">*</span></label>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cm_description',array(),array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'cm_description'); ?>
 </td>
```

based on the change classification, I must decide where Change Description must be a drop Down or a text field.
This must be done using Javascript.

Comment: where is `change_desc()`??

Comment: I have updated my code, change_desc will not come.

Comment: any update on this? can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this -

1. Change the code to -

`<label>Change Description <span class="required" id="desc_req_note"    style="display:none;">*</span></label>`

`<span id="cm_desc_select" style="display:none;"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'cm_description', array(), array('empty'=>'Select Change Description')); ?></span>`

`<span id="cm_desc_input" style="display:none;"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'cm_description'); ?></span>`

`<?php echo $form->error($model,'cm_description'); ?>`

2.
`$('#cm_classification_id').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var cm_desc_select_elem = $('#cm_desc_select');
    var cm_desc_input_elem = $('#cm_desc_input');
    if(val === COMPARE_WITH_YOUR_VALUE) {
        $(cm_desc_select_elem).show();
    } else {
        $(cm_desc_input_elem).show();

    }
 });`

I hope is helps for a quick fix.

Comment: this works, but when I again change the drop down option, it again disappears